# Why is my electrical circuit only 60 volts?

Tags: electrical

I uninstalled some fluorescent tube lighting in my living room because I didn't like the quality of the light. After uninstalling it I wired up a standard 15A outlet on the wires that previously went to the light fixture.

The problem: I tested the voltage at the fixture both on the terminals and in the slots with my multimeter and am only getting 60 volts.

I removed the transformer that was hooked into the lights so it is no longer on the circuit, so that can't be it. Also, it was a standard 3 wire (white/black + ground) configuration.

Am I missing something? How/why would an outlet in a home even be wired for 60 volts?

Additional Info:
It is on a circuit with two ceiling fans, both of which are operating normally. It is not switched.

Comment: Do you have any other circuits you can check? I ran into a similar problem, but the low side was 90 volts and the other circuit was 140 volts. My 220v source was unbalanced!

Comment: Yes, please do check the voltage on other circuits in your house!

Comment: I'll check, but there are a couple of ceiling fans and light fixtures on the same breaker that seem like they are getting enough current unlike my new outlet which produces a very dim light when I plug a lamp into it. Should I test a circuit on the same breaker?

Comment: How did you shut off the power while you were doing the wiring?

Comment: I flipped the breaker.

Comment: Might want to verify your meter is good (calibrated), too.  Can you compare w/ another meter?

Comment: Well, I plugged a lamp into that outlet and it barely lit up. Even if the meter isn't accurate, there is clearly something wrong with the outlet.

Comment: To me it sounds like an open circuit (quite common) if when rewiring white was treated as a neutral when it was part of a switch leg this could cause problems. With a light barely lighting was there a second light in the room doing the same? Lights in series is another possibility (the lights and fixtures are wired in parallel.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at where the light fixture was removed and where the receptacle's installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would proceed VERY carefully after finding this kind of situation (at least, if you measured the 60 volts when the fixture was on!). This can point at several **really unsafe** conditions:

- Floating neutral (this is really dangerous: it means you have 60V here and 180V somewhere else in the worst case!)
- non standard circuit (eg centre-tapped 120V, or you accidentally turned a partially disconnected transformer into an autotransformer, or some load is in series).
- high wiring resistance
- something severely overloading that circuit,
- something wired in upstream (dimmers, transformers, rectifiers (eg old school half-brightness switches)) that you are unaware of
- a broken or wrongly used meter (also, very dangerous!)